# IOS OpenGL gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart Error

Tags: ios, opengl-es, runtime-error

I am having major issues a with a  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart error.

Currently I am rendering a cube and a line. If I render just the cube or just the line the error arises about 20% of the time. If i render both i get the error about 90% of the time.

I have read online that this is a bug in ios and there is nothing that can be done. However, other OpenGL programs like unity do not have this issue. So I must be doing something wrong

The following is a simplified version of the code i am using.

```
-(void) setUp{
    m_context = [[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2] autorelease];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context];

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_renderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_renderbuffer);
    [m_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER,    m_renderbuffer);
}



-(void) render{
    //[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:m_context];  Error seems to happen more frequent if I uncomment these lines
    // glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_framebuffer);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [self renderCube];  // VBO
    [self renderLine];  // NON VBO

    [m_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER]; <---- Error Here
}



-(void) renderCube
{
     glUseProgram(m_cubeProgram);

     glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureHandle);

     glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniformHandles[UNIFORM_PROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, m_projectionMatrix.m);
     glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniformHandles[UNIFORM_MODELVIEW_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, m_modelMatrix.m);

     glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_cubeIndexVBO);

     glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_POSITION]);
     glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_TEXCOORD]);

     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_cubeVertexVBO);
     glVertexAttribPointer(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_POSITION], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
     glVertexAttribPointer(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_TEXCOORD], 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 3));

     glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, m_numberOfIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0              );

     glDisableVertexAttribArray(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_POSITION]);
     glDisableVertexAttribArray(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_TEXCOORD]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);  // Desperate attempt to fix the issue
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);          // this too
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);           /// this too
}





-(void) renderLine
{
    glUseProgram(m_lineProgram);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniformHandles[UNIFORM_LINE_PROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, m_projectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(m_uniformHandles[UNIFORM_LINE_MODELVIEW_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, m_modelView.m);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_LINE_POSITION]);

    float linVertices[]= {...};

    glVertexAttribPointer(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_LINE_POSITION], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 3, lineVertices);

    glLineWidth(3.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(m_attributeHandles[ATTRIB_LINE_POSITION]);
}
```

Comment: Does your frame rendering happen to take an extremely long time (>2 seconds or so)? I've seen this error kick in when the built-in driver watchdog timer kills rendering due to a single frame taking way too long (usually in response to an expensive shader).